# how to config CEDET to auto-complete for MinGW g++

Tags: emacs, g++, mingw, cedet

I configed the CEDET to auto-complete for MinGW gcc, it works great, however I can't get the g++ work for the completion of member of STL libs. For example, I can't auto-complete the std::string variable to get the c_str() or other functions:

```c
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string s;
    s.       // no pop up member functions here
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the config part of my .emacs:

```lisp
;; setting up for semantic-mode
(semantic-mode 1)
(require 'semantic/bovine/c)

(setq MinGW-64-base-dir 
    "D:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include")
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
     (concat MinGW-64-base-dir "/crtdefs.h"))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
     (concat MinGW-64-base-dir "/yvals.h"))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
     (concat MinGW-64-base-dir "/vadefs.h"))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file 
     (concat MinGW-64-base-dir "/comdefsp.h"))
(semantic-c-reset-preprocessor-symbol-map)

(defconst user-include-dirs
  (list ".." "../include" "../inc" "../common" "../public"
        "../.." "../../include" "../../inc" "../../common" "../../public"))
(defconst win32-include-dirs
  (list "D:/MinGW/include"
        "D:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
    "D:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include"
    "D:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++"
    "D:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include-fixed"
))

(let ((include-dirs user-include-dirs))
  (when (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (setq include-dirs (append include-dirs win32-include-dirs)))
  (mapc (lambda (dir)
          (semantic-add-system-include dir 'c++-mode)
          (semantic-add-system-include dir 'c-mode))
        include-dirs))
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration?  A right configuration for the MinGW g++ is wanted.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this article by Alex Ott: [A gentle introduction to CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html)?

Comment: @Francesco Yes, I read it (maybe I skipped something) and the class member that I defined can auto-complete well, but the STL lib's member or member functions can't auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample on my Ubuntu system without your config, and it provided more completions than I knew what to do with.  I'll guess that Semantic doesn't know where some include file is, or doesn't have the right pre-processor symbols set up.

If you do:

```
M-x load-library RET semantic/analyze/debug RET
```

you can then put the cursor on your sample and do:

```
M-x semantic-analyze-debug-assist RET
```

and it will give you a bunch of hints, and additional commands to try to dig into the problem.

I know you set up all your includes and preprocessor files in your setup.  That part seemed ok to me.

The code in semantic/bovine/gcc.el is supposed to query your GCC for the the type of info your provided which is used to find things like your STL header.  The compiler provides some kinds of #define values that STL headers use, and might not be in your other ming headers you provided for preprocessor symbols.

Unfortunately, this has hard-coded names for the C++ compiler it tries to use.  If your compiler has some other name, you might need to edit the gcc.el source file to get it to work.  If you do, email the cedet-devel mailing list so we can make the change in CEDET.

Alternately, load up wherever your string.h file is, and find the definition it should use for completion.  Look to see which #if statements filter it out, then use:

M-x semantic-c-describe-environment RET

to see how that might be related.